# Convert each directory within SVN trunk to different GIT repositories

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to convert a SVN repository to a GIT repository. Inside my SVN `/trunk` directory I have multiple directories:

```
/trunk
  /apps
  /site
  /services
  /scripts
/branches
  ...
/tags
  ...
```

If I run the command `git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt https://mysvnrepo.com.br/svn/myapp/ c:/mygitrepo` it will create only one GIT repository with all directories within.

Basically what I want is to create a GIT repository for each directory inside `/trunk` so I would have 4 different GIT repos: `apps`, `site`, `services` and `scripts`.

Also I would like to create only GIT `main` branch, ignoring other SVN branches.

How can I do this with the `git svn` command?

Comment: "*…one GIT repository with all directories within.*" Now split the repository in four: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first converting the SVN repository into *one* Git repository.

Then use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) on that Git repository in order to extract 4 repositories out of 4 subfolders in it.

```
git filter-repo --path apps
git filter-repo --path site
git filter-repo --path services
git filter-repo --path scripts
```

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58983975/6309).